# Is it feasible to save data from SparkStreaming to Cassandra from Spark Workers

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, datastax-enterprise

SparkStreamingContext is created on driver and it can't be serialized. So, we cannot access this object on workers. Now to make use of distributed nature of Spark we would be processing the data/stream on workers. Hence, it make sense to save data directly from workers rather than collecting all the data to driver which might give OOM.

I have the scenario like this where i need to apply some business logic and finally need to store the data to cassandra. So, how do i do it?

```
DStream.foreachRDD{ x => x.foreachPartition {  some logic and finally Store the data to cassandra }  }
```

Comment: saveToCassandra should do the job. But whether that will save the data locally or on a different machine in cluster depends on which node the data belongs to in the ring. I'm also working on a similar problem.

Comment: @Sreekar I am working on Spark1.6 with scala 2.10. So, how would be able to create connection to Cassandra inside foreachRDD reason being spark context won't be available there.

Comment: get sparkContext on streaming context object. It's available. eg: ssc.sparkContext.cassandraTable() or saveToCassandra on the RDD should work. You can set the hostname and port etc. on the sparkContext if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use datastax's spark-cassandra-connector (https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) which allows to store JavaDStream directly into Cassandra DB.

```
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions;

Map<String, String> columnNameMappings;
JavaDStream<MyTableData> myDStream;
javaFunctions(myDStream).writerBuilder("mykeyspace", "my_table",
            CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(MyTableData.class, columnNameMappings)).saveToCassandra();
```

Comment: Could you please tell me for the scala. I am working on the same

Comment: Check this sample program in scala at https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkStreamingIntro.html

Answer (score 1):

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test App")
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "X.X.X.X")
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "xxxxx")            
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "xxxxx")
```

`SparkConf` is the object in the context which holds your Cassandra connection configuration, so set it there.

`SparkContext` is part of `StreamingContext`, but you don't really have to worry about it. If you need to access `SparkContext` or current `SparkConf` then you can do that like this

```
StreamingContext ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))
ssc.sparkContext   => Your Spark Context object
ssc.sparkContext.getConf   => Your SparkConf object
```

Coming to how to save to Cassandra part, it can be done like this:

```
// messages is the InputDStream in this example
messages.foreachRDD( x => { 
    // Write business logic
    x.saveToCassandra("keyspace_name", "table_name")
}
```

Comment: My business logic would run on Worker. So, again the problem is i would need to collect data on driver to save it in cassandra and my driver would be overloaded. So. how to avoid this problem

Comment: `SOMERdd.foreachPartition(Partition => {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)  } `  Like in case of mysql We create the connection on workers and destroy it over there. But how we do achieve if we have the database as cassandra.

Comment: I think moving to Spark 2.0.0 would be good as it has the capability to create multiple streams (workers) and all share the same streaming context. Also, the connection creation/termination will be taken care of by Spark automatically as long as you are giving proper credentials to SparkConf object, it's different from MySQL.